# How do coroners/forensic scientists know if an assault occurred during one's life or post-mortem?

Tags: autopsy, cadavears, coroner, forensic-pathology

I'm interested in forensic science, and continue to be surprised by the breadth of information that can be revealed from a body or other physical/forensic evidence.

Warning:  Graphic question.

I've been listening to the Podcast, ["Hollywood & Crime"](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2017/jan/12/hollywood-a-podcast-that-scratches-at-the-dark-underbelly-of-films-golden-age). The notorious 1947 murder case of Elizabeth Short (aka the [Black Dahlia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Dahlia)) is a central theme of this podcast.

I know that forensic science back then is definitely not what it is today, but they sure knew more than me! Anywho, in one of the podcast's episodes it states that the coroner concluded that the victim, Short, had her face disfigured (a smile carved in her cheeks) prior to her death. But... the body was found drained of blood, and completely washed cleaned. Thus, **how do coroners/forensic scientists know if the assault occurred during one's life or post-mortem without evidence of blood to imply either way?**